# Ansible string manipulation in list

Tags: ansible, list-comprehension

I am loading a text file into a list where each item is a line in the txt file.
The list I am receiving looks like this:

```
list = ['firstline\r\n', 'secondline\r\n', 'thirdline\r\n',.....]
```

I want to delete all the escape characters from the end of each string to receive the following list:

```
list = ['firstline', 'secondline', 'thirdline',.....]
```

In python I would do a list comprehension that looks like this:

```
new_lst = [var.replace('\n').replace('\r','') for var in list]
```

I am looking for the ansible equivalent but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.
I have found the map\extract features that could be piplined after loading my txt file but I'm having trouble using them in my case.
Here is my code so far:

```
 vars:
 contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/ANSIBLE_SANDBOX/Ofek/ACL updating/iot_prov_acl.txt').split('\r\n')}}"
```

I though about adding map or extract like so:

```
 vars:
 contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/ANSIBLE_SANDBOX/Ofek/ACL updating/iot_prov_acl.txt').split('\r\n') | map/extract()}}"
```

but didn't how to to apply it to my problem.

Thanks in advance!